# Кеширование путей к файлам в PHP

Tags: php, php-fpm

Доброго времени суток!
PHP запущен как fpm демон. Судя по докам, результаты функции file_exists, stats и.т.д кешируется. 
Так вот вопрос, при запуске PHP как FPM, результаты этих функции кешируется на время отдельного запроса или на время жизни FPM процесса?

Comment: ссылки на доки. Что то нелогично кэшировать `file_exists` как минимум, когда его используют предполагаеться что фаил может быть удалён в любой момент времени, если не только в рамках скрипта щас проверим.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.clearstatcache.php  на офф сайте

Comment: интересный вопрос `file_exists` есть но он у меня на fpm не кэшируется почемуто....

Comment: Судя по эксперементам кэширует только на время выполнения скрипта

Comment: Искренне не видел, чтобы результаты кешировались... по крайней мере, когда запускал: `unlink(__DIR__.'/test.txt'); $test[] = file_exists(__DIR__.'/test.txt'); file_put_content(__DIR__.'/test.txt', '1'); $test[] = file_exists(__DIR__.'/test.txt');` Получил: `Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 1
)`